# ¿Cómo recorrer un arreglo con API de WooCommerce y PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

Agradecería mucho quien pueda orientarme con lo siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente arreglo, es un registro de un producto en `woocommerce` `wordpress` que tiene a su vez tres variaciones: 1837, 1838 y 1839.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (

        [variations] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1837
                [1] => 1838
                [2] => 1839
            )



    )
)
```

Necesito poder recorrer el arreglo de todos los productos que me devuelve el `api` de `woocommerce` para poder luego modificar el precio que tiene cada variación.

Tengo entendido que primero tengo que recorrer todos los productos con:

```
$woocommerce->get('products'):
```

Luego recorrer todos las variaciones de cada producto con:

```
$woocommerce->get('products/<id-variacion>/variations')
```

y por ultimo realizar el `update` del precio de cada variación con:

```
$data = [
    'regular_price' => '10.00'
];

  $woocommerce->put('products/<id-producto>/variations/<id-variacion>', $data)
```

por los momentos tengo esto, pero el script tarda mucho en ejecutarse y solo son 10 productos.

```
$productos = $woocommerce->get('products', ['per_page' => 99]) ;
foreach ($productos as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'nombre producto: '.$value->name;
    echo 'id producto: '.$value->id;
$variaciones = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$value->id.'/variations',['per_page' => 99]);
foreach ($variaciones as $clave=>$valor) {
    print_r($valor->attributes);
    echo 'id variacion: '.$valor->id;
    echo 'sku variacion: '.$valor->sku;
    echo 'precio: '.$valor->price;
    $data = [
    'regular_price' => '10.00'
    ];
$woocommerce->put('products/'.$value->id.'/variations/'.$valor->id.'', $data);
}
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que ya logré la solución, si hay una manera más optima o estoy errado en algo agradecería mucho la corrección o la orientación.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'url', 
    'ck_0000000000000000', 
    'cs_0000000000000000',
    [
        'version' => 'wc/v3',
    ]
);

$sap = file_get_contents("sap.json");
$sap_array = json_decode($sap, true);

print_r($sap_array);

$productos = $woocommerce->get('products', ['per_page' => 99]) ;
//$variaciones = $woocommerce->get('products/10/variations');
//print_r($variaciones);
//print_r($productos);


foreach ($productos as $key=>$value) {
    $variaciones = $woocommerce->get('products/'.$value->id.'/variations',['per_page' => 99]);

    echo '<h1>nombre producto: '.$value->name.'</h1>';
    echo '<h2>id producto: '.$value->id.'</h2>';

    foreach ($variaciones as $clave=>$valor) {
        echo '<h3> Atributos:</h3>';
        print_r($valor->attributes);

        echo '<h3> id variacion: '.$valor->id.'</h3>';
        echo '<h3> sku variacion: '.$valor->sku.'</h3>';
        echo '<h3> precio: '.$valor->price.'</h3>';

    foreach ($sap_array as $sapkey=>$sapvalue) {

        if ($sapvalue['id_justime'] == $valor->sku) {
            echo '<h3> sku sap: '.$sapvalue['id_justime'].'</h3>';
            echo '<h3> precio sap usd: '.$sapvalue['price_usd'].'</h3>';
            echo '<h3> precio sap cpl: '.$sapvalue['price_clp'].'</h3>';

        $data = [
            'update' => [
                [
                    'id' => $valor->id,
                    'regular_price' => $sapvalue['price_clp']
                ]
            ],
        ];

            $woocommerce->post('products/'.$value->id.'/variations/batch', $data);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Básicamente lo que hago es recorrer todo el arreglo de producto, extraigo el id del producto para luego usarlo en el update de los precios de la variación.

El único inconveniente que tengo ahora es que el script dura mucho en ejecutarse.

Comment: Diculpa, casualmente estoy trabajando con este tema pero no puedo obtener la imagen del producto. Estoy recorriendo el array pero no logro obtener la imagen, como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias!